# Disabling the postgres superuser Role

Tags: postgresql

i would know what is the impact of disabling completely **postgres** user Role from postgres database and revoke all privilege from the user?
by running the following command:

```
postgres#psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres NOSUPERUSER;"
postgres#psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres NOCREATEROLE;"
postgres#psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres NOCREATEDB;"
postgres#psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres NOREPLICATION;"
postgres#psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres NOBYPASSRLS;"
postgres#psql -c "ALTER ROLE postgres NOINHERIT;"
```

thank you.

Comment: If you do that, you essentially lock yourself out of your server completely. If you want to make it secured, disallow remote connections for the superuser and choose a really strong password.

Comment: thank you for your response, but i would tell you that i have another superuser ```superole``` and my database work normally, i would know the impact of other ```database maintenance operations```